# Installing Apache Cordova

Tags: apache, cordova

I'm new to this of Apache Cordova. I'm trying to follow the documentation but cannot understand it very well. It says that for prerequisite I need to install the correspondant SDK. I did install Android Studio. then downloaded the Node.js and then tried to run the installation but it doesn't start I don't understand why it doesn't start. There is another things that I need to do so it starts installing?[image: node.js Command prompt]

Any help will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the clue is in the message -- just run the command `npm install -g cordova` from the normal DOS command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to **install 1)node.js 2)apache ANT 3) Java JDK & JRE 4) Android SDk & Eclipse** and then after all installation you have to set this **all software path into environmental- variable. and then fire your npm install -g cordova.** without this all software installation and there path setup your phoneGap application will not created. and still you have any confusion and any question related software installation and there path setup then again tell me i will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you want to install Node.js in order to get the 'npm' commands to work.

https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest/

You can download the latest version of Node.js from there... I was on a Mac, so I did the .pkg download. Install the appropriate one for your development machine.

After that, the 'npm' commands for Cordova will work. Hope this at least gets you started! :)